# How do I calculate the cost of an item where the price goes up based on how many you have?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an item in a game that costs $100

Every time you buy it, the cost goes up (cost * 1.02)

If I have 25 of these things, how would I calculate what the cost of the item should be?

Comment: The price of the 25th item should be $100\cdot 1.02^{24}$, because the price of the first item is $\$100$. The price of all 25 items is $100 \sum_{i=0}^{24} 1.02^i=100\cdot \frac{1.02^{25}-1}{0.02}\approx 3,203.03$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cost is $100 \cdot 1.02^{25} \approx 164$.

Answer (score 1):

The first item costs $100$ dollars.

The second item costs $100 + 0.02 \cdot 100 = 100(1 + 0.02)$ dollars.

The third item costs $100(1+0.02)(1+0.02) = 100(1+0.02)^2$ dollars.

The $n$th item costs $100(1+0.02)^{n-1}$ dollars.

If $n=25$ then this item costs about $\$160.84$, and the next one you buy will be about $\$164.06$.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential models.

$cost*{(up by(1.02))}^{number of times}$